# After calling retrofitCall.enqueue neither the OnFailed block is executing neither the OnResponse

Tags: api, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

When I click on the button, `callRetrofit` function begins execution, but the `mycall.enqueue` none of the `onFailure` or `onResponse` codeblocks are executing. There is nothing I can get from the logcat.

Here is my `callRetrofit` function:

```
private fun callRetrofit() {

    val file = File(selectedFile.toString())

    val filePrt = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)

    val MP2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Photo", "Tasveer", filePrt)

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val jsonPlaceholderApi = retrofit.create(Jinterface::class.java)
    val mycall = jsonPlaceholderApi.uploadFile(authoo, MP2)

    mycall.enqueue(object : Callback<RequestBody?> {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<RequestBody?>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("dikkat", t.message.toString())
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<RequestBody?>, response: Response<RequestBody?>) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Donne", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            textView.text = response.body().toString()
            Log.e("ressponse", response.body().toString())
        }
    })
}
```

And here's the interface:

```
interface Jinterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media")
    fun uploadFile(
        @Header("Authorization") authorization: String,
        @Part() file: MultipartBody.Part
    ) : Call<RequestBody>
}
```

Comment: Did you give storage permission for your app? If not you will not be able to upload and it should show in the log data.I already tested with your api, got the response null. It means  your code is working fine. Check permission.

Comment: Hey thanks for the time, Yeah I have given both read and write permissions.